# What does the phrase "point-blank" mean in "she refused point-blank to join in"?

Tags: expressions, doubled-words

> So she refused point-blank to join in.

What does the expression *point-blank* mean in this context? Could you give me some more examples of situations where this phrase could be used?

Comment: After having looked it up in a dictionary, what questions do you have? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/point-blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an expression used to say that someone very bluntly did something with emphasis.  Usually when used it means that there was some historical context involving the action in that the person doing something point-blank could/should have been expected to do that.  Often there is a connotation of hostility or at the very least conveying that you do not want to be questioned about your actions.

> Usage:
>
> - I told my husband point-blank if he hits me one more time that I am leaving.
> - "Dad can I borrow your Porsche?"  Dad replies, "Steve, point-blank no!"

Answer (score 3):

There's an interesting discussion of the origins of the expression here:

http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=22750

Usually used of a gun, it has become a metaphor for *manner*.

> POINT BLANK adjective; adverb
>
> [1591] Aimed *straight* at the mark or target *without allowing for the drop in a projectile's course [due to gravity]*, firing straight at the target – point blank –one may hit the target if one is close enough.
>
> [1598] (figurative): Without hesitation, deliberation, or equivocation; plainly, bluntly, directly, frankly; abruptly or rudely: *She told him point-blank that he was not welcome.*

Comment: @medica - Feel free  :-)

Comment: thanks! I enjoyed that article. I never caught the gravity part before. :)

Comment: .... _I'm_ free!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - lol! and congrats on new privileges. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: With the way edits are shown, I found it hard to sort out where the necessary 'adverb' was left out. We'll blame Erik. On the other hand, he _does_ prefer a decent ruby ale to American lager.